# How to pre select cell on UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on a project where I want to read images from "Saved Photos" and a album named "myAlbum" and list them on UICollectionView with provision to multiple select like this

http://screencast.com/t/Y8VCgrWbH

When user click on myAlbum images from myAlbum album is shown and when user click on Gallery images from gallery in shown each time user click on one of the two buttons I reload UIcollectionView data. I am also saving selected images in a mutable array and remove if unchecked. I want to compare image with selected array and then show that cell already selected in

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

when user navigates both buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the cells that you want to select, and then call this delegate method:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Put this maybe in `viewWillAppear`. You should be able to figure out the indexes that you need to select if you've saved the data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, authorize the multiple selection of your collection view :

```
self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

After, implement the two delegates methods :

```
#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Update Cell Selection
    [_selectedItems addObject:[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Update Cell Selection
    [_selectedItems removeObject:[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
}
```

`_data` is your array with all your objects, and `_selectedItems` is an NSMutableArray for hold the current item selected or not.

Modify the aspect of your cell here :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Finally, for more information, you can have a look [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-collection-view-tutorial/).